# Django: Force select related?

Tags: django, django-orm

I've created a model, and I'm rendering the default/unmodified model form for it. This alone generates 64 SQL queries because it has quite a few foreign keys, and those in turn have more foreign keys.

Is it possible to force it to *always* (by default) perform a `select_related` every time one of these models are returned?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can create a custom manager, and simply override `get_queryset` for it to apply everywhere. For example:

```
class MyManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(MyManager, self).get_queryset().select_related('foo', 'bar')
```

(Prior to Django 1.6, it was `get_query_set`).

Comment: How do we do this when using models.QuerySet?

Comment: I think you need to provide more information, or some example code, as to what you mean; if you have a QuerySet, then you can call `select_related` on it directly.

Comment: `as_manager` returns an initial manager object; the documentation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/#from-queryset explains how to use a custom manager along with a custom queryset. You should be able to define your manager as above, define your custom queryset, and then use something like `objects = MyManager.from_queryset(MyQueryset)()`

Answer (score 40):

Here's also a fun trick:

```
class DefaultSelectOrPrefetchManager(models.Manager):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._select_related = kwargs.pop('select_related', None)
        self._prefetch_related = kwargs.pop('prefetch_related', None)

        super(DefaultSelectOrPrefetchManager, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super(DefaultSelectOrPrefetchManager, self).get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)

        if self._select_related:
            qs = qs.select_related(*self._select_related)
        if self._prefetch_related:
            qs = qs.prefetch_related(*self._prefetch_related)

        return qs


class Sandwich(models.Model):
    bread = models.ForeignKey(Bread)
    extras = models.ManyToManyField(Extra)

    # ...

    objects = DefaultSelectOrPrefetchManager(select_related=('bread',), prefetch_related=('extras',))
```

Then you can re-use the manager easily between model classes.  As an example use case, this would be appropriate if you had a `__unicode__` method on the model which rendered a string that included some information from a related model (or anything else that meant a related model was almost *always* required).

...and if you *really* want to get wacky, here's a more generalized version.  It allows you to call any sequence of methods on the default queryset with any combination of `args` or `kwargs`.  There might be some errors in the code, but you get the idea.

```
from django.db import models


class MethodCalls(object):
    """
    A mock object which logs chained method calls.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self._calls = []

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        c = Call(self, name)
        self._calls.append(c)
        return c

    def __iter__(self):
        for c in self._calls:
            yield tuple(c)


class Call(object):
    """
    Used by `MethodCalls` objects internally to represent chained method calls.
    """
    def __init__(self, calls_obj, method_name):
        self._calls = calls_obj
        self.method_name = method_name

    def __call__(self, *method_args, **method_kwargs):
        self.method_args = method_args
        self.method_kwargs = method_kwargs

        return self._calls

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.method_name
        yield self.method_args
        yield self.method_kwargs


class DefaultQuerysetMethodCallsManager(models.Manager):
    """
    A model manager class which allows specification of a sequence of
    method calls to be applied by default to base querysets.
    `DefaultQuerysetMethodCallsManager` instances expose a property
    `default_queryset_method_calls` to which chained method calls can be
    applied to indicate which methods should be called on base querysets.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.default_queryset_method_calls = MethodCalls()

        super(DefaultQuerysetMethodCallsManager, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super(DefaultQuerysetMethodCallsManager, self).get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)

        for method_name, method_args, method_kwargs in self.default_queryset_method_calls:
            qs = getattr(qs, method_name)(*method_args, **method_kwargs)

        return qs


class Sandwich(models.Model):
    bread = models.ForeignKey(Bread)
    extras = models.ManyToManyField(Extra)

    # Other field definitions...

    objects = DefaultQuerysetMethodCallsManager()
    objects.default_queryset_method_calls.filter(
        bread__type='wheat',
    ).select_related(
        'bread',
    ).prefetch_related(
        'extras',
    )
```

The python-mock-inspired `MethodCalls` object is an attempt at making the API more natural.  Some might find that a bit confusing.  If so, you could sub out that code for an `__init__` arg or kwarg that just accepts a tuple of method call information.

Comment: This really saved my day - instead of writing tons of `ModelForm`s, overriding `ModelChoiceField`s until the cows come home. (Espacially if the `MyModel.__unicode__()` uses what needs to be `select_related`.

Comment: Great answer. This solves the majority of my n+1 related issues

Comment: Note: `get_query_set` was [deprecated in Django 1.6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.6/#get-query-set-and-similar-methods-renamed-to-get-queryset). It should be replaced with `get_queryset` now.

Answer (score 3):

Create a custom [`models.Manager`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/) and override all the methods (`filter`, `get` etc.) and append select_related onto every query.  Then set this manager as the `objects` attribute on the model.

I would recommend just going through your code and adding the `select_related` where needed, because doing select_related on everything is going to cause some serious performance issues down the line (and it wouldn't be entirely clear where it's coming from).

Comment: Then I have to override all the form fields in the model form so that I can set the queryset manually...

Comment: Well, you can always go with my first suggestion.  I was just warning you about the possible detrimental performance issues you may run into down the line.  There are ways to do it just for the `ModelForm` without overriding everything, but the answer will really depend on what exactly you need to do.  If you want help with it, just create another question with more details.

Comment: Well, I've got an Address model that has links to postal code, city, province and country. It'll pretty much never be displayed without those fields, so I figured I might as well include it by default.

Comment: The just add the custom manager I suggested on that `Address` model, and you'll be good to go.

Comment: @Izzad-DinRuhulessin Been years now, but I think I was using them to look up the city/province/country -- they weren't part of a larger address.