# Django select from multiple models

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-queryset

What is the best way to select data from multiple models?

For example

```py
class User(models.Model):
    ...

class UserFeature1(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...

class UserFeature2(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...

...

class UserFeature30(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...
```

If you have 30 tables with foreign key to User table, it will be hard to write 30 `select_related` queries as `User` is not the model that holds the foreign key. Reason being it's a one-to-many relationship, 1 user can have multiple feature each.

Even writing raw SQL query is hard with so many models.

What is the cleanest method to use? And what is the most performant method? Taking in consideration of calling them from template.

Thanks

Comment: One idea is to do each query separately, then do an union.

Answer (score 0):

You can force select_related with override QueryManager. [you can read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892729/django-force-select-related)

```py
class MyManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(MyManager, self).get_queryset().select_related('foo', 'bar')
```

Comment: sorry, I read through but I don't understand it. My example, `User` can't do `select_related` because it doesn't have foreign key. e.g. 1 User -> Many UserFeature1

Comment: can you write a raw SQL to fetch your queryset?

Comment: I just want to see your SQL to understand your requirement